# Concatenate/join multiple rows of strings into one single row for the entire dataframe

Tags: python, data-cleaning, data-preprocessing

I have a dataset of 60,000 tweets in a CSV file. Some of the tweets are multiline, but i need to make all of them a single line. As an example:
[image]

As you can see from the above example the tweet is multiline. I want to make it into a single row:

> index Tweet ID "On the other side we could do it over I will hold you closer Maybe not this time But I find you again and again again #missuniverse #emin", Label

I have tried with the following code but getting the following result:

```
df7['Tweet']= df7['Tweet'].str.join(sep=' ')
```

[image]

Instead of joining, the code is actually splitting further. This is not helping. What I am missing ?

Please note that this dataframe contains multiple instances of the example given above, and I want to make a single row for the whole dataset.

Comment: You should do this before reading it as a dataframe. How do you differentiate between a multiline tweet and a normal tweet

Comment: Can you please elaborate, how do i process it before reading the csv file? Is there any example?

Comment: You can read it as a file and do the necessary preprocessing line by line. It is easier to do. You  just need a way to differentiate between multiline tweets and tweet endings. Seems like you have a way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution you could use:

```
df7['Tweet'] = df7['Tweet'].str.replace('\n', ' ')
```

Remember that in ASCII encoding line breaks are represented by the *Escape Sequence*: `\n`.

Replacing this with a whitespace will get you the result you are looking for.

Comment: Worked like a charm. For a few it didn't but for the most it did. Thank you so much. God bless you.